# volume of solid of revolution about y-axis of region bounded by $x=1-y^2$ and the y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the "volume of the solid that results when the region bounded by $x=1-y^2$ and the y-axis is revolved around the y-axis"

This is from a worksheet that my teacher gave me.

my attempt: $$2\int_0^1 (-x+1) dx$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We need to rotate about the line $x=0$ (y-axis), and we want to express $x$ as a function of y:  $x=1-y^2$ (as given).  That's a horizontal parabola, intersecting the y-axis at $y =-1$ and $y = 1$. The aim here is to integrate with respect to $y$, where $x = 1-y^2$ is the radius, which varies as $y$ varies.

$$\begin{align} \pi \int_{-1}^1 (1-y^2)^2\,dy & = \pi \int_{-1}^1 (1- 2y^2 + y^4)\,dy\\
& = \pi\left(y - \frac {2y^3} 3 + \frac{y^5}5\right)\Bigg|_{-1}^1
\end{align}$$
I'll let you take it from here: just be careful with the signs.

Comment: can't we use the symmetry of the graph and write $2\pi \int_0^1     (1-y^2)^2 dy$?

Comment: Sure you can, either way you'll get the same result.